# WebAuthn on Chrome on Windows: Skip Windows dialog in favor of Chrome dialog

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, webauthn

In developing our passkey integration I'm encountering unusual behavior in Chrome on Windows.

On my PC, when I register a new physical key I see this Windows dialog.

[image: Windows passkey-setup dialog]

When I enable the virtual authenticator environment in the Chrome Dev Tools I get this Chrome dialog instead.

[image: Chrome passkey-setup dialog]

However, someone testing the application for me on another PC, without using the virtual authenticator environment, gets the Windows dialog first. If they click Cancel in the Windows dialog, *then* they get the Chrome dialog.

Is there anything I can do to nudge the browser towards delivering a more consistent experience? I'd rather always show the Chrome dialog if possible.

For reference, this is the virtual authenticator environment in the Chrome Dev Tools:
[image: Virtual-authenticator environment in Chrome Dev Tools]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that lots of enterprise users have to use a physical security key one or more times a day. So there's a strong desire not to put extra clicks in their way and thus to jump directly to the Windows system UI. But the Windows UI doesn't support using phones as authenticators, so sometimes the browser UI is needed as hitting escape is quite non-discoverable.

Quite how that balance is struck has varied over time and might change again in the future. You can see the *current* logic [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/webauthn/authenticator_request_dialog_model.cc;l=1165;drc=f85c63321f9dd8cfdc5483fe60cea665c52f25d1) if you want to craft requests that trigger the browser UI. But the intent is that sites should do the obvious thing and the UI should be fairly reasonable.

Comment: Could you summarise what characteristics the request would currently need to trigger the browser UI? It's a bit dense without any prior knowledge to guide me. Or I'm a bit dense. I've tried messing with the resident-key requirements but I'm still not getting the browser UI, just the Windows UI.

Comment: If you're doing a `create` call (which I'm guessing from your mention of resident-type requirements) then setting `requireResidentKey` should do it. I.e. registering on webauthn.io will show the browser UI.

Comment: With the virtual-authenticator environment disabled I only get the Windows dialog. I don't get the Chrome dialog even after hitting cancel, regardless of which option I enter for "discoverable credential." With the virtual authenticator environment I only get the Chrome dialog, and never see the Windows dialog - also regardless of what I enter for `requireResidentKey` or `residentKey`. The Chrome dialog is preferable IMO but it looks like I don't have any choice in the matter since most people will not be using the Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Are you using a current version of Chrome? I booted up a Windows machine and consistently get the browser UI when clicking "Register" on webauthn.io, as I would expect. Can you check chrome://version?

Comment: I have the current version of Chrome, `109.0.5414.75 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Bypass)`. Maybe the difference is that I'm on windows 10?

Comment: I've asked and we're not sure how that happens. Do you have Bluetooth support on the machine? (If you don't have Bluetooth then there's quite possibly no option other than the Windows system API and so Chrome will jump to it rather than show a single-item menu.)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, @agl. My PC does not have a BT radio. I asked someone else to test with a PC that does have a built-in BT radio and they do get the Chrome UI - tho they still have to first click Cancel on the Windows UI.

Comment: So it would seem that basically the answer is _No_, to my question of "Is there anything I can do to nudge the browser towards delivering a more consistent experience?"

Answer (score 2):

To make the answer more readable by not having to open the complete comment section of the accepted answer:

When a device does **NOT** have Bluetooth, there is no other option than the authentication methods that are provided by the operating system. Therefore, in this issue, the Windows popup will always be shown with only Windows Hello and Security key as an option.

Comment: Credits go to @agl